# AWS js sdk - are credentials mandatory

Tags: aws-sdk-js

I have an S3 bucket with public read access.  I have a web app and within it I want to use the AWS SDK JS to make clientside calls to list objects in the bucket.

I have no use case for credentials but it seems when initialising the client that credentials are required as I keep getting a 'Missing credentials in config' error.

```
import S3 from 'aws-sdk/clients/s3';
var s3 = new S3({
    apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
});
// the above initialises without error
var params = {
    Bucket: 'my_bucket',
    Delimiter: '/',
    Prefix: "some-path/"
}
// throws Missing credentials in config
s3.listObjects(params, function (err, data) {
    if(err)throw err;
    console.log(data);
});
```

My questions are therefore:

1. Are credentials are required and if not, how is my config incorrect?
2. If credentials are required how would i configure them for the purposes of clientside calls to a public bucket.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so apparently it seems credentials are required.  This seems a little strange to me when using the SDK for publically accessible calls which require no auth?

http://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-configuring.html#Configuring_the_SDK_in_the_Browser

Answer (score 0):

Credentials are definitely required, fwiw, here's how I do it for simple testing:

```js
import { config as env } from 'https://deno.land/x/dotenv/mod.ts' // https://github.com/pietvanzoen/deno-dotenv
import { S3Client, ListObjectsV2Command } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/@aws-sdk/client-s3' // https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3

const {AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY} = env()

// https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/modules/credentials.html
const credentials = {
    accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
}

// https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/interfaces/s3clientconfig.html
const config = {
    region: 'us-east-1',
    credentials,
}

// https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/classes/s3client.html
const client = new S3Client(config)

export async function list() {
    // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/interfaces/listobjectsv2commandinput.html
    const input = {
        Bucket: 'my_bucket'
    }

    // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/classes/command.html
    const cmd = new ListObjectsV2Command(input)
    
    // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/classes/listobjectsv2command.html
    return await client.send(cmd)
}
```